# Optimization of a program in python

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to solve this problem on HackerRank:

> Animesh has N empty candy jars numbered from 1 to N with infinite capacity. He performs M 
>   operations. Each operation is described by 3 integers a, b and k where a and b are index of >the jars and k is the number of candies to be added inside each jar with index between a and >b (both inclusive). Can you tell the average number of candies after M operations? 
>   I have written the below code in Python 3:

```
def operate(a, b, k, array):
    for i in range(a - 1, b):
        array[i] += k
def mean(array):
    return int(sum(array) / len(array))
splitinput = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
candy = []
for i in range(splitinput[0]):
    candy.append(0)
for j in range(splitinput[1]):
    splitinput2 = input().split()
    operate(int(splitinput2[0]), int(splitinput2[1]), int(splitinput2[2]), candy)
print(mean(candy))
```

It works, but times out on some test cases. How could I approach making this faster? I'm been coding in Python for a while, but the finer points of optimization still elude me.

Comment: The place to start with performance is to see what is the slowest. You should use a profiler: http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html though it may not be as useful in a small program like this

Comment: I would have done that, but I was fairly certain that the bottleneck was in the `for j in range(splitinput[1])` part. Such programs can often be surprising, though, so I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't care where the candies are. As long as you know how many candies there are and how many jars, you can compute the mean. Thus, you can just keep one count of all candies:

```
jars, ops = map(int, input().split())
candies = 0
for i in range(ops):
    a, b, k = map(int, input().split())
    candies += k*(b-a+1)
print candies / jars
```

This avoids having to keep track of N separate counts or increment k counters for each operation. When you get large k values, this is very important.

Comment: It should be `b - a + 1` though (SO won't let me edit less than 6 characters)

Comment: @rmartinjak: You're right. Fixed. The weird `>` characters in the question threw me off.